# keyboard in UIWebView shows and then hides itself on input focus

Tags: ipad, ios, uiwebview, keyboard

I have a page that's loading into a UIWebView (which takes 100% of the screen) on an iPad.

When I touch a text field, the page positions the text field to the right place and the keyboard starts to come up, but then it turns around and goes back down and blur is called on the input field.

When I try this same page in mobile Safari, the keyboard is able to deploy successfully.

I can't figure out what the rules are for the keyboard to show successfully and stay up = and why this is different for uiwebview than safari.

All my research on the subject has yielded no answers.

Comment: Are you handling the view resizing correctly when the keyboard comes up? If not, this might be a cause of unexpected behaviour.

Comment: how do I size the view correctly?  I have handlers for the keyboard events already.  I just don't know what conditions the keyboard requires to stay up...

Comment: Sounds like you are changing/renouncing the firstresponder in one of your webView delegate methods. Can you please show the code for those delegates?

Comment: Do you see "resignFirstResponder" in your code? @MihaiTimar has already stated that. You will have to provide some code for better answers.

Comment: Question was asked 3+ years ago. But, still the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol methods enables us to customize the behavior of a `UITextField`. Are you using `[textField resignFirstResponder]` ? Please share code or screenshots of the blur you mentioned?

Answer (score 1):

Without having any code posted in your question, I am speculating that the keyboard going back down occurs only when the HTML text field is touched prior to the final call to `UIWebViewDelegate webViewDidFinishLoad:`

To test this, first set your `UIWebView.delegate` to the `UIViewController` that owns it (or whatever object owns the `UIWebView`). Then implement these delegate methods.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSString *urlString = request.URL.absoluteString;
    NSLog(@"%@ with URL = %@", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), urlString);

    return YES;
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    NSString *urlString = webView.request.URL.absoluteString;
    NSLog(@"%@ with URL = %@", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), urlString);
}
```

Run your app and make note of the number of times that `webViewDidFinishLoad:` is called.  (If your web page contains multiple frames or includes things like Google Analytics, it will be called multiple times.)

Try touching the HTML text field after `webViewDidFinishLoad:' is called for the final time.  Does the keyboard stay up? (I would think so).

If that works, next try to get a touch in before the final call to `webViewDidFinishLoad:'.  Does the keyboard animate up but then back down?

Comment: That is indeed what is happening, but the question is how to work around this.  Any ideas?